# Find div ID and use to call associated Javascript variable with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have several fish images, within links, which are listed like so...

```
<a href="#" class="trigger"><img src="img/fish1.png" id="fish1"/></a>
<a href="#" class="trigger"><img src="img/fish2.png" id="fish2"/></a>
```

I want to take id 'fish1', 'fish2', ect. (based on which is clicked), and use a variable to replace some text.

The name of the variables are...

```
var fish1Hunger
var fish2Hunger
```

And the function I want to call with a variable is...

```
$(function() {
    $('a.trigger').click(function() {
        $('#popUp h3').html(REPLACE WITH VARIABLE ASSOCIATED WITH THE FISH);
    });
});
```

How can I call the variable associated with the IMG id?

Comment: Check out the `this` variable.

Comment: I know about this variable... How would that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window[e.srcElement.id+"Hunger"];`

Put that inside your click event with `e` being the event (`function (e){...`) and it should access the variable as long as it is in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/anukig/3/edit)*

```
var fish1Hunger = "Fish 1 is hunger!! Feed him!"
var fish2Hunger = "Fish 2 is hunger!! Feed him!"


$('a.trigger').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ImLookingFor = $(this).find('img').attr('id')+'Hunger';
    $('#popUp h3').html(eval(ImLookingFor));          
});
```

Comment: As was pointed out to me, you're replacing the HTML with the ID, not with the variable associated with the ID.

Comment: @j08691 well :) this one will not decrease speed, and it's not going through a form or anything similar, so it's fine IMO.

Comment: it is not that bad, there is just no need for eval as you can access variable from global scope via `window["variable-name"]`

Comment: @vittore njehm I know that but as already (well) answered by Amaan I tried to clean my mess :)